# How to share contact

Tags: java, android, share

I have an app which requires phone authentication to use.
After authentication I want to set a feature which will be able to share other contacts to people.

For example, I am A and in my contacts 3 people use my app named B, C and D. 
Suppose I want to share B's contact to D. How do I do that?

Same as sharing contact on Whatsapp.

Searched quite a bit but not getting how to achieve this.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Where are your contacts stored and how? How are you sending any data to a "contact"? SMS?

Comment: I have stored in an activity called homescreen... so i can use intent and go to that activity but how do i click on one of the items there and fetch it? @cricket_007

Comment: Fetch what? Can you show your code as a [mcve]? Have you tried storing the contacts in SQLite rather than in the activity?

Comment: I have stored it in firebase and the activity just fetches it @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, please still edit your question to include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this : I'm sure it will be of help**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

contactNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);

Button buttonPickContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickcontact);
buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);             


 }});
}

@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode == RQS_PICK_CONTACT){
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

  String number =       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

  //contactName.setText(name);
  contactNumber.setText(number);
  //contactEmail.setText(email);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Following would be the XML for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/pickcontact"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pick Contact" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/contactnumber"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of Achieving this is via Intent. You can store the data in an Intent and pass it to another Screen via

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

and then in the other screen retrieve the same intent via:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra();
```

Also, you will have to take user permission to access contacts and then pass the contacts  via intent. Permissions need to be added in the Manifest Files.

Comment: So i go to the activity where all contacts are stored... then what to i do? like i need to code of how to fetch the contacts from that activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void shareContact(String[] args) {

    String lookupKey = null;
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY }, Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String lookupKey = cur.getString(0);
    }
    if(lookupKey!=null){
        Uri vcardUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Contact Name"); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

More details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts#CONTENT_VCARD_URI

Comment: Like i can just use an intent and go to the activity where all contacts are shown... but after that how do i select one of the contacts i want is my question